# Advantages of non-white background in typography

Tags: print-design, website-design, typography, color-theory

Financial Times website has a non-white background, namely, `255,240,229` in sRGB. However, the text is not black: `50,48,46` (the title is black).

[image]

Are there any advantages of such color scheme for web or for paperback version?
As I understand, printed edition uses similar colours (unfortunately, I've never seen a printed version).

Here is a small comparison of four background/text color options. The rightmost is the one ft.com uses. It is typeset in Georgia, which, as I understand, is used on the website.

[image]

Comment: Brand recognition by using familiar format.

Comment: @joojaa I agree, but is there any typographical purpose?

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 4):

One possible benefit would be that lesser contrast causes less eye strain. Going way back to Tschichold, he advised to use off-white paper and a very dark grey type instead of pure black. I'll try to add a more formal reference when I have more time.

Avoiding pure black and white contrast is fairly common but that really depends on the medium. For example, printing dark grey type will often result in halftones, which would destroy the benefits of having lesser contrast.

Like joojaa commented, brand recognition is also at play here since FT uses a very distinct colored paper for their publication.